# Passing multiple variables in a URL

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need help with this.
I'm passing two variable through a html link  as shown below :

```
<?php
//loop through the array
foreach ($precost1 as $value): ?>
<ul><li><a name="farmname" href="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/farms/'.$farm;'/'.$value->farmcycle;?>"><?php echo $value->cyclename;?></a></li></ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the link is not working as expected, it  ignores the second variable $value->farmcycle  any help with the right syntax please?

Answer (score 1):

.$farm;'/'

The semicolon closes the line, try using . instead.

Answer (score 1):

semicolon ends php statement, use .(dot) as concat operator

```
foreach ($precost1 as $value) {
  echo '<ul><li><a name="farmname" href="'.base_url().'uploads/farms/'.$farm.'/'.$value->farmcycle.'">'.$value->cyclename.'</a></li></ul>';    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After `$farm` you had a `;` and forgot to concatentate `.`

```
<ul><li><a name="farmname" href="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/farms/'.$farm .'/'.$value->farmcycle;?>"><?php echo $value->cyclename;?></a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
//loop through a list of farmnames and create link for each listed farmname
foreach ($precost1 as $value): ?>
    <ul><li><a name="farmname" href="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/farms/'.$farm.'/'.$value->farmcycle;?>"><?php echo $value->cyclename;?></a></li></ul>

<?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, are you sure you want to be creating a `<ul>` tag for each new item?

Try putting this outside of the foreach, so you are just creating a `<li>` for each item.